# Drupal 6: duplicate theme function in two themes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I have a regular and mobile theme for a site; there are currently a couple of duplicate functions in the `template.php` of each theme, which do some text munging on the same fields. That is, the markup is the same for these fields in both themes.

How can I impose DRY and only have the logic in one place?

I understand I could [make the regular theme inherit](http://drupal.org/node/225125) the mobile theme, but this doesn't seem like a "proper" solution, since the themes are quite different at the end of the day. Even more so as this would require ex-post-facto manipulation of the preprocess functions, and overriding mobile CSS and JS files - seemingly creating as much work and future WTH as it solves.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would love to see the proper answer for this.

All i can think of is making a module that holds the duplication of functionality. A library module if you will.

So I'm making this "answer" as a conversation starter.

in: (mobile)template.php

```
preprocess_page(&$vars){
 mymodulename_pagepreprocess($vars,'mobile');
}
```

(desktop)template.php

```
preprocess_page(&$vars){
 mymodulename_pagepreprocess($vars,'desktop');
}
```

You can have preprocess-functions in modules as well btw. But it might be nice to send witch template as an argument.(you could however extract this from the global $theme)

Comment: +1 for moving common functionality to a module. If there are no other themes to be served, I would also second the suggestion of using 'real' preprocess-functions in the module, thus removing the need for the indirectin in the template.php files. And even if there are other themes to be served, the preprocess-function in the module could add the 'munged' values as separate variables, so that it would be up to the themes templates to use the version they need.

Comment: A module makes theoretic sense, but it just seems ridiculous to go through the coding overhead of creating and maintaining a module just to hold helper functionality for manipulating output for two CCK fields for use in two themes - which is what I'm working with here.

Answer (score 1):

How about you make a base theme which holds the functions, and implement both as sub-themes of it.

Or just the mobile theme a sub-theme, and the PC theme is the base?

[Creating a sub-theme](http://drupal.org/node/225125)

Comment: Hmm, an abstract parent theme. That's worth a look, I hadn't thought of that. But the idea of a straight mobile sub-theme, I refuted in the question; I believe it had to do with not wanting to call the non-mobile preprocess functions in mobile.